# Can we detect touch events when the phone screen is locked in iOS? I want my app running and accessible even when the phone screen is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, screen-lock

Can we detect ***touch events*** when the phone screen is locked in iOS? I want my app running and accessible even when the phone screen is locked.

Comment: No it is not possible. But you can create an app Widget, which is not really "running and accessible even when the phone screen is locked" but it's as close as you will get.

Comment: Thanks all, I almost knew the answer, but it was one of my client's insane requirement, so I had to ask.